# Unable to run blockchain project with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, geth

**Below is the version  description:**

1. **Install geth (for accession console)** - Version: 1.9.21-stable
2. **Install solidity(run solc file from terminal)** - Version: 0.4.26+commit.4563c3fc.Darwin.appleclang
3. **Install Parity(connect RPC connect for port 8584)** Version : - Parity-Ethereum/v2.7.2-stable-d961010f63-20200205/x86_64-apple-darwin/rustc1.41.0
4. Install Metamask(browser extension)

I have created testnet account from metamask and import it into our system via command : geth account import  --datadir  "account address" --password "password"  "pvt key"
but when we go to the get console via (geth console --testnet 2>>geth.log) and run eth.accounts[0] we received **0eth**

[As you can see the screenshot I have 4.9962 ETH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKdOb.png)

**My Solc file**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract mortal {
    /* Define variable owner of the type address*/
    address owner;

    /* this function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract */
    function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; }

    /* Function to recover the funds on the contract */
    function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); }
}

contract greeter is mortal {
    /* define variable greeting of the type string */
    string greeting;

    /* this runs when the contract is executed */
    function greeter(string _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    /* main function */
    function greet() constant returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

**Create a Contract and Deploy**

```
@contract = Ethereum::Contract.create(file: "#{Dir.pwd}/contracts/greeter.sol")
@tx = @contract.deploy("Hello")
@link = "https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/#{@tx}"
```

Whenever I run the program I am  getting **IOError (Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have enough funds. Required 1000000 and got: 0.):**

My question is:

1. how we can get balance for testing in order to make a transaction and create a contract.
2. How we can check the transaction is successfully created and deploy into the blockchain.

Comment: 1. you can check the balance in your parity cli beforehand. 2. get your transaction hash and search it on etherscan,

Comment: I have created account via geth and when we go to the geth console it's showing 0.

Comment: which blockchain are you connected to? you must transfer some balance from the account which already have some ether.

Comment: When you create an account it comes with 0 ethers you must have to get the ethers from some account or faucet.

Answer (score 0):

you need to feed your wallet with ether test. You can achieve that going to https://faucet.ropsten.be/ , filling your testnet wallet etherbase and then earn ether test